# GET JSON provides two values, I want to add these two togther using php, and then return to callback

Tags: php, json

`$_GET['numberofwelds'];` & `$_GET['numberofconwelds'];` are sent to this script using GET JSON. I want to add these together, and then use json_encode to send a total back to the callback (in another php script) .  If both `$_GET` 's are empty, then I want nothing to happen. How should I change this?

```
 $numberofwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
    $numberofconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];

    if (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && $_GET['numberofwelds'] != '' {
     $numberofwelds + $numberofconwelds = $sum_total; 
    echo json_encode($sumtotal);
    } else {
     exit()
     }
```

Comment: The value you echo is so simple, it's literally already proper JSON. There's no need to use `json_encode()`, your script would be working fine without it and when you run `JSON.parse()` in JS, or wherever you're using this value it will validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are trying to access your `$_GET` variables without checking they exist *first*.

Secondly, you should be **throwing Exceptions** instead of just calling `exit()` or `die()`. You can then log them with `$e->getMessage()` or write them to the local filesystem.

Finally, you need to **validate** your data. Make sure it is what you expect it to be.

```
if (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && isset($_GET['numberofconwelds']))
{
    // Now we know both values definitely exist, VALIDATE them
    $numwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
    $numconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];

    if (is_int($numwelds) && is_int($numconwelds))
    {
        // Calculate your total
        $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
        echo json_encode($total);
    }
    else
    {
        // We get here because your GET variables do exist but they aren't 
        // numbers as you expect (you or someone else has sent rubbish data)

        // You want to do nothing, although I would return an error in your json
        // to be displayed to the user or logged by the consumer of the service
    }
}
else
{
    // We get here because your GET variables simply don't exist. They haven't been
    // passed in as you are expecting them to be

    // You want to do nothing, although I would return an error in your json
    // to be displayed to the user or logged by the consumer of the service
}
```

Always code defensively.

---

I'm going to show you what I would do in this situation.

```
if (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && isset($_GET['numberofconwelds']))
{
    $numwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
    $numconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];

    if (is_int($numwelds) && is_int($numconwelds))
    {
        $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;

        $response = array("status" => "success", "message" => $total);
        echo $response;
    }
    else
    {
        $response = array("status" => "failure", "message" => "GET params were not numbers");
        echo $response;
    }
}
else
{
    $response = array("status" => "failure", "message" => "GET params do not exist");
    echo $response;
}
```

Then, in your consuming service (most likely a JavaScript / jQuery AJAX call), you can do the following:

```
.done(function(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);

    if (data.status === "success") {
        // Yay, we got a success back
        console.log("The total is: " + data.message);
    } else if (data.status === "failure") {
        // Uh oh, something's gone wrong server-side
        console.log(data.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So in the original example using json_encode, would I use `echo json_encode("error" => "You did not enter numbers");` for the errors. To pass  to `.error()` in Jquery, when using .get() or .post() ?

Comment: @mattnewbie Nope, your `.error()` callback is only executed when a **HTTP error** occurs. So if you throw an exception instead of returning json, you'll find that your `.error()` will be called because of a **HTTP 500** error. Also, the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) state you should be using `.done()` and `.fail()` callbacks instead of the *deprecated* `.success()` and `.error()` :-)

Comment: In the original example, everything gets passed through to `.success()` (which should be `.done()` really), and then you just parse your `json.status` and do what you want.

Comment: One final question if I may:  The `"status" => "failure",` part throws  an exception, which calls .fail() because of a HTTP 500 error?  Is that what you mean? Sorry if that question sounds silly, coding is quite new to me. Thanks for all the support, I really appreciate it

Comment: No worries. Nope, you either throw an exception, *or* you return json containing the failure reason. Throwing an exception is `throw new Exception()`. You can try `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');` and you'll hit your AJAX `.error()` (or `.fail()) on the way back, but really, just pass things to your `.done()` via a json status and handle it from there. Much more readable code-wise.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
    if ($_GET['numberofwelds'] != '' && $_GET['numberofconwelds'] != '') {
     $numberofwelds + $numberofconwelds = $sum_total; 
    echo json_encode($sumtotal);
    } else {
     exit()
     }
```

to this

```
if ($numberofwelds  && $numberofconwelds ) {
     $sum_total = array(
      'sumTotal'  => $numberofwelds + $numberofconwelds,
     );
     echo json_encode($sum_total);
}else {
     exit();
}
```

Comment: No. This requires register globals.

Answer (score 0):

Please always check existence of the array keys with `isset()` construction or `array_key_exists()` function.

```
if (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && $_GET['numberofwelds'] != '' && isset($_GET['numberofconwelds']) && $_GET['numberofconwelds']  != '') {
  echo json_encode(array("total" => $_GET['numberofwelds'] + $_GET['numberofconwelds']));
} else {
  exit();
}
```

**UPDATE**

With `is_numeric()` function this code should be more robust:

```
if (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && is_numeric($_GET['numberofwelds']) && isset($_GET['numberofconwelds']) && is_numeric($_GET['numberofconwelds'])) {
  echo json_encode(array("total" => $_GET['numberofwelds'] + $_GET['numberofconwelds']));
} else {
  exit();
}
```

[PHP reference: array_key_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

[PHP reference: isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Thanks. I'm slightly confused by your top line.  Won't `['numberofwelds']) && $_GET['numberofwelds'] != '' ` check both to make sure they are empty? Why do I need anything after the `!=` on the top line ?

Comment: You are using two array keys, so you need to check both. It's a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

```
$numberofwelds = json_decode($_GET['numberofwelds'], true);
$numberofconwelds = json_decode($_GET['numberofconwelds'], true);

$mergedJson = array_merge(numberofwelds, numberofconwelds);

echo json_encode($mergedJson);
```

This should do it. It grabs the json, decodes and turns it in to an array (second parameter of json_decode set to true) and then combines them.